# export to Android in ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm having a problem every time I export to Android this error occurs:

> CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic need call android build tools in the process, so you should tell them where to find these tools.

Add below to `environment path`

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
```

Modify if your install locations are different.